# postDate keeps jumping ahead when editing an entry

Tags: postdate

When I edit an existing entry the post date jumps ahead by an hour meaning I have to manually remove it before saving the changes.

I thought it may have something to do with the timezone but this is set to the correct timezone.

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Yes! Is it in Firefox? And are you in a timezone that is not UTC? If so (like me) then it will jump by the offset I think. It is essentially a bug with FF (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1227499) because if you type `new Date()` into the console of FF you get the wrong time there.

Comment: Yes I'm using FF and I'm set to the London timezone. I'm going to test it out on chrome! Thanks for the link

Comment: No worries! Yes I chatted with Brad of P&T and we just agreed to not use FF ...

Comment: Ran into this too. It's a very strange bug in FireFox. Even in the latest version  - 46.0.1. Just as well there are other decent browsers about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding as an official answer since we've had a handful of reports about this.  Best we can tell it's a bug in Firefox that happens when you live in a non-UTC timezone.  There are several Date related bugs in Mozilla's bug tracker, but this one looks to be the most relevant: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1227499